# Importing OBJ file in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, wavefront, qvector

I'm new in using Qt Creator (version 4.10.0, based on Qt 5.13.1). I have taken the `customitemgraph example` and I would like to replace the existing `.obj` files with new ones.
I have downloaded some free models from the web. Some of these work but others don't.

Here's two exemples.

An extract of the `.obj` file opened with notepad, which is working

```
...
vn 0.3531 -0.8627 -0.3620
vn 0.3815 -0.9243 -0.0148
usemtl Default_OBJ
s 1
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4
f 2/2/2 5/5/5 6/6/6 3/3/3
f 4/4/4 3/3/3 7/7/7 8/8/8
...
```

a not working case:

```
...
vn -0.1013 -0.8959 -0.4325
vn -0.1003 -0.8978 -0.4287
usemtl Body
s 1
f 225536//133387 225537//133388 225544//133389 225543//133390
f 225537//133388 225538//133391 225545//133392 225544//133389
f 225538//133391 225539//133393 225546//133394 225545//133392
f 225539//133393 225540//133395 225547//133396 225546//133394
...
```

When it doesn't work the error message is:

```
tot 4ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file c:\Users\qt\work\install\include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 448
```

#### What I've tried

I have opened the `.obj` files with notepad and seen that in the working cases there is only one `/` character separating numbers, and in the not working cases there are `//` two slashes with no numbers in between. After substituting the double slashes with a single one nothing changes, the problem keeps showing.

I've tried some simple `.obj` files taken from [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm) to diagnose the problem further but none of these examples works.

Am I missing something? Is there a way around this? Another way to use my `.obj` files inside this example? Thanks for the help.

Comment: There should be no slashes between those *face* values according to [this spec](https://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm).  However ultimately an index is being used that is too large.  You can find out where by running your code in the debugger and catching that exception.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you but the site you linked is the one I used for my handcrafted examples and they don't work. I'll give it a try with the debugger and update my answer anyway...

Comment: I was wrong about the slashes anyway (I didn't look down enough).  Make your parser cope with double-slashes but to avoid the crashing check the length of vectors before accessing them and generate an error message before returning gracefully (or just throwing an exception if you don't feel like being graceful, which is also OK).

Comment: @trojanfoe I just looked into my impl. for Wavefront Obj. It reads face indices _with _ slashes. If I only had noted where I found the spec. I wrote according to... Though, the index values really look large.

Comment: Yeah it's possible that `//` shows an absence of a value and the `.obj` are just plain corrupt.

Comment: May be, there is a limit about how large indices are supported in Qt (assuming the indices are not out of range). I remember that OpenGL Performer (cancelled long ago) used 16 bit values for indices to safe memory...

Comment: @trojanfoe Even about `//`, you might be not correct. It just could be that indices are unused by intention. I try to dig deeper. - In my code, I found a note that `//` could be due to unused texture coordinates (e.g. if there is no texture on that face).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `QMesh` from the Qt 3D module to render complex 3D files. [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/85670/how-to-load-an-stl-file-using-qmesh/4) you can find an example on how to use this class with `.stl` files but, if you dig through the documentation, you can find the parts where it uses `.obj` files.

Comment: It woks perfectly with `.stl`, still have some problems with `.obj`. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I must admit, today is the first time I used QtCreator as well as QML.

In opposition to OP, I used an even simpler sample for my experiments:

the [**Qt 3D: Wireframe QML Example**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html)

After some fiddling, I came to the following receipt:

1. Open **`wireframe`** example in QtCreator.
   The sample uses a Wavefront OBJ file `trefoil.obj`.
2. Locate the `trefoil.obj` on disk.
   I found it under `.../Qt/Examples/Qt-5.13.0/qt3d/exampleresources/assets/obj`.
3. Store the sample files `cube.obj` and `cubeN.obj` from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302552/7478597) into this folder.
   The absence of the referenced material file `master.mtl` is in this example regardless.
   As far as I understood, the materials are defined in QML. – Any loaded material would be overridden in any case.
4. In the project treeview of QtCreator, add the sample files `cube.obj` and `cubeN.obj` to `Resources`/`.../Qt/Examples/Qt-5.13.0/qt3d/exampleresources/obj.qrc`/`assets`/`obj`.
   Opening `.../Qt/Examples/Qt-5.13.0/qt3d/exampleresources/obj.qrc` afterwards in a text editor, I found:

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>assets/obj/trefoil.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/toyplane.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/ball.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/plane-10x10.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/material-sphere.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/cube.obj</file>
        <file>assets/obj/cubeN.obj</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

5. I copied the file `QML`/`TrefoilKnot.qml` to `QML`/`Cube.qml` and `QML`/`CubeN.qml` and replaced the `source` entries respectively – `Cube.qml`:

```cpp
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0

Entity {
    id: root

    property real x: 0.0
    property real y: 0.0
    property real z: 0.0
    property real scale: 1.0
    property real theta: 0.0
    property real phi: 0.0
    property Material material

    components: [ transform, mesh, root.material ]

    Transform {
        id: transform
        translation: Qt.vector3d(root.x, root.y, root.z)
        rotation: fromEulerAngles(theta, phi, 0)
        scale: root.scale
    }

    Mesh {
        id: mesh
        source: "assets/obj/cube.obj"
    }
}
```

6. I added the files `Cube.qml` and `CubeN.qml` to `Resources`/`wireframe.qrc`.
7. I changed `QML`/`main.qml` to add the entities `Cube` and `CubeN`:

```cpp
    TrefoilKnot {
        id: trefoilKnot
        material: wireframeMaterial
    }
    Cube {
        id: cube
        material: wireframeMaterial
    }
    /* Excluded:
    CubeN {
        id: cubeN
        material: wireframeMaterial
    }*/
```

After starting the application, I got the following result:

[image: Snapshot of modified wireframe example with Cube]

I tried the same for `CubeN` and the result looked similar:

[image: Snapshot of modified wireframe example with CubeN]

I'm on Windows 10 (64 bit) and used Qt 5.13.0 with Qt Creator 4.9.1.

---

Concerning the [**`objgeometryloader.cpp`**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/geometryloaders/default/objgeometryloader.cpp.html):

According to what I found in sources, the following OBJ commands are supported:

- `v` defines a vertex coordinate
- `vn` defines a vertex normal
- `vt` defines a vertex texture coordinate
- `f` defines a face (triangle or triangle fan)
- `o` defines an object with name.

Additionally, empty lines are skipped and comments if hashmark `#` appears at begin of line (with no indentation).

Other lines with e.g.

- `mtllib` reference to material file
- `usemtl` activating a certain material from material file
- `g` starting a group
- `s` activating a certain smoothing group

seem to be just ignored.

Considering that this plug-in is a geometry loader, this seems reasonable.

---

I also saw plug-ins for scene parsers on woboq:

[**`qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/`**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/)
+ [**`assimp/`**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/assimp/)
+ [**`gltf/`**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/gltf/)
+ [**`gltfexport/`**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/gltfexport/)

I googled a bit but couldn't find anything what is directly related to my current Qt Version 5.13 except [Open Asset Import Library, version 4.1.0](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-attribution-assimp.html).

Answer (score 3):

Concerning:

> I've tried some simple .obj files taken from [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm) to diagnose the problem further but none of these examples works.

I took the sample from [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm) as well – `cube.obj`:

```
# This cube has a different material
# applied to each of its faces.
mtllib master.mtl
v 0.000000 2.000000 2.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 2.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 2.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000
v 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
# 8 vertices
g front
usemtl red
f 1 2 3 4
g back
usemtl blue
f 8 7 6 5
g right
usemtl green
f 4 3 7 8
g top
usemtl gold
f 5 1 4 8
g left
usemtl orange
f 5 6 2 1
g bottom
usemtl purple
f 2 6 7 3
# 6 elements
```

The sample refers to `master.mtl` which I couldn't find anywhere.

Hence, I wrote one from scratch – `master.mtl`:

```
# Create as many materials as desired
# Each is referenced by name before the faces it applies to in the obj file

newmtl red
Ka 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000

newmtl blue
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000

newmtl green
Ka 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000

newmtl gold
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000

newmtl orange
Ka 1.000000 0.500000 0.000000
Kd 1.000000 0.500000 0.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000

newmtl purple
Ka 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ns 0.000000
```

Then, I tried it with our loader and got this:

[image: Snapshot of cube.obj]

Then, I modified `cube.obj` to add normals.

This is a sample where the double slashes (`//`) occur in face indices (due to missing texture coordinates).

The file with normals – `cubeN.obj`:

```
# This cube has a different material
# applied to each of its faces.
mtllib master.mtl
v 0.000000 2.000000 2.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 2.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 2.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000
v 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 -1 0
# 8 vertices
g front
usemtl red
f 1//1 2//1 3//1 4//1
g back
usemtl blue
f 8//2 7//2 6//2 5//2
g right
usemtl green
f 4//3 3//3 7//3 8//3
g top
usemtl gold
f 5//4 1//4 4//4 8//4
g left
usemtl orange
f 5//5 6//5 2//5 1//5
g bottom
usemtl purple
f 2//6 6//6 7//6 3//6
# 6 elements
```

[image: Snapshot of cubeN.obj]

Not sure whether this does prove anything except that the samples aren't completely broken (in our loader).

Comment: I tried to use the files your provided. I put `cubeN.obj` and `master.mtl` inside the same folder and then called `item->setMeshFile("cubeN.obj");` inside my code but the error still shows up.

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

Comment: @Sandra I modified the samples. After looking into source [objgeometryloader.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/geometryloaders/default/objgeometryloader.cpp.html), I'm uncertain whether tabs (`\t`) could be a problem and removed all of them (or replaced them by spaces). Could you try again? (The source I mentioned earlier in another comment was plainly wrong - my fault, sorry.)

Comment: @Sandra Reading a little bit more in the source, I see two possible issues: 1. Only spaces are considered as delimiters between values (and I didn't find any replacement of tabs with spaces); 2. comments (prefixed with `#`) may not have indentation. I'm not sure that this is according to the spec., but I'm sure that our loader is tolerant about this. Hence, the files might have been worked on our side but not in QtCreator. (But, I will investigate a little bit further...)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your new samples but it's not working (same error message)

Comment: @Sandra Damn! (No further ideas.) There might be more issues with the loader. While googling a bit, I found some QtBugs concerning the OBJ loader but nothing what matched exactly... Conversion to something else? The doc. mentions "Stanford Triangle Format PLY" and "STL (STereoLithography)" as well as "Autodesk FBX". STL, I would consider as last resort. AFAIK, it supports triangles only -> materials and textures would be lost.

Comment: I have already tried PLY, STL and FBX. I always get the same error. Maybe  the issue is somwhere else... I will try some other solutions. Thanks

Comment: I tried starting from scratch with the same example and only changing the `.obj` files. Still getting the same error.